# NestJS throwing error Cannot find module 'jest-util'

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I'm running a NestJS api with extensive code, everything is working fine, and it has almost full code coverage with all kinds of different mocks.

While trying to implement a test for the provider of a new module, I was prompted with this error:

```
Cannot find module 'jest-util'
Require stack:
- /node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js
- /node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js
- /node_modules/@jest/core/build/jest.js
- /node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js
- /node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest.js
- /node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (../node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (../node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (../node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
  at require (../node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

I managed to isolate what was causing this behavior and it was this snippet of code below:

```
jest.mock("fs", () => ({
   promises: {
       writeFile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined),
       readFile: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(Buffer.from('test')),
       unlink: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined),
   },
}));
```

Jest functions are being used all over the rest of the code below and above this statement, so it kinda doesn't make sense for me what is going on.

I expect some people are gonna wanna see the jest section on the package.json so I've added it below, but I don't think that's where the problem lies, as its working in more than 1000 different tests, all very similar to this one.

```
"jest": {
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "json",
  "ts"
],
"rootDir": "src",
"testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.(t|j)s"
],
"coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
"coverageReporters": [
  "json-summary",
  "json",
  "html"
],
"testEnvironment": "node",
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/test/config/envMock.ts"
]
},
```

jest version is 25.1.0

Anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: looks like you didn't run `npm install`? also, run `npm ls jest-util` (or `yarn why jest-util` dependending on which package manager you're using)

Comment: @MicaelLevi should I use `npm install` if I use yarn? I've run `yarn install` plenty of times though. Anyways, below is the code for yarn why jest-util:

`yarn why jest-util
yarn why v1.22.17

=> Found "jest-util@25.5.0"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "jest#@jest#core" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "jest#@jest#core#jest-util"
   - Hoisted from "jest#jest-cli#jest-util"
   - Hoisted from "jest#@jest#core#@jest#console#jest-util"`

Comment: if your project uses Yarn, then you shouldn't use NPM. Looks like that package was installed. Not sure what's going on here tho

Comment: from the _require stack_, jest is trying to load that module as a global one, I guess. Which command have you ran?

Comment: @MicaelLevi what do you mean with which command? Within the code its the one I listed above, but in the console I've ran the `yarn why jest-util`. To build, install and update I've been using `yarn build`, `yarn` and `yarn install` respectively.

Comment: I believe, though, that the problem does not reside on the packages per se, as the code runs in its entirety using jest-util everywhere but here

Comment: I mean, which command did you run to get that error

Comment: `yarn test contract.service`, contract.service being the file being tested, and contract.service.spec being the test file

Comment: and the npm-script `test` is just `jest`, right? Run `yarn why jest`

Comment: Yeah, `test` is equivalent to `jest`.
`yarn why jest` result:

`Found "jest@25.5.4"
info Has been hoisted to "jest"
info This module exists because it's specified in "devDependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "56KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "872KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "49.07MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 134`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `restoreAllMocks` after the already existing `clearAllMocks` on the `beforeEach` block of the testing module and the error went away.

Don't know exactly why though. I guess that maybe it has something to do with the mocks' states at certain points in the code, but I have no idea really.